# How do I get part of the name of my Azure resource group and use it to create a new Azure resource name?

Tags: json, azure

I am brand new to authoring my own JSON ARM templates.

I am trying to be proactive in my template creation by building in a few shortcuts.

The question I have is...in JSON, how do I grab characters from my Azure Resource Group Name to copy to a new resource that I am creating?

This is what I have so far.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {

        "ResourceTypeAbbr": { 
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "STG"
        }

    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [

        {
//How do I make this part work?//

            "name": "[concat(resourceGroup().name)(parameters(ResourceTypeAbbr),('001'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "storageaccount1"
            },
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
    }
  }
```

So can I use resourceGroup().name and get the characters from index position 0-16 and make it a part of my new Azure Resource name?

So, if my Azure Resource Group name is CAP-OOO-USWE-PRD-RG-001 ...Id' want my new Azure Resource to get the name CAP-OOO-USWE-PRD-STG-001 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to build name using a mix of parameters and variables such as:

```
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
 "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
    "ResourceNamePrefix": { 
        "type": "String",
        "value": "CAP-OOO-USWE-PRD"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "ResourceName": [concat(parameters('ResourceNamePrefix'), '-STG-001')]
},
"resources": [

    {
        "name": variables('ResourceName'),
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "storageaccount1"
        },
        "properties": {
            "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the concat method and append any other info you would like to. For example, assuming you want to use the resource group and build around this value:

`"name": [concat(resourceGroup().name, parameters('ResourceTypeAbbr'), '-001')]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JasonJ: did this help? Please let me know or accept this answer. Thanks!